# npm audit fix not changing anything

Tags: node.js, npm

I think this is a pretty basic question but i've been stuck for a while:

I am trying to use `npm audit fix` to clean up an old repo that has many security vulnerabilities.  When I run, I see that I get the following output:

```
fixed 3534 of 3576 vulnerabilities in 1926 scanned packages
  42 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated
```

However, I see that nothing in package-lock.json was changed.  So It doesn't appear that audit has actually done anything?  When I run `npm install` I can again see the following:

```
found 3576 vulnerabilities (3550 low, 10 moderate, 14 high, 2 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Does this mean that the audit process was not able to resolve any of these issues?  If so, how do I approach resolving these?

Comment: what dependencies do you have? for example when I use nexe as a dependency in windows Kali emulator, it will always say vulnerability

Comment: but if u said half a year this problem lasted, i assumed u switched environments and re-installed nodejs and copied files placed them in new folder, deleted old folder, re-install dependencies.. all that.. and if that's the case this is VERY interesting

Answer (score 22, accepted):

What causes it: This would seem to be a known bug in `npm` for which no one has (yet) publicly worked out the cause, at least not that I can find. However you can see it reported in [an issue in the current `npm` issue tracker](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/301) which links to [an issue in the archived `npm` issue tracker](https://npm.community/t/npm-audit-fix-claims-to-have-fixed-vulnerability-but-it-doesnt/9901).

How to fix: When I encounter this behavior in `npm`, I do this:

```
$ rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json shrinkwrap.json npm-shrinkwrap.json
$ npm install
```

However, I don't think that works all the time. But if you haven't done that, it's worth a shot. [@Kshewengger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6891406/kshewengger)'s suggestion to update `npm` is a good thing to try too. They suggest `npm install -g npm` and try that first, but if that doesn't work and if you don't mind an updated `package-lock.json` file format and other changes, you can also try `npm install -g npm@7`. As of this writing, `npm install -g npm` will give you `npm@6.14.9` and `npm install -g npm@7` will give you `npm@7.0.15`.

Comment: @BruceK can you accept this answer please?

Comment: @YanickRochon As it says in the answer: "I don't think that works all the time." Update npm instead, as the answer instructs.

Comment: @YanickRochon Oh well. Like it says in the answer: "it's worth a shot." The fact that it doesn't work in all situations is expected. Seems to work in most situations, but definitely not a fix for all situations.

Comment: Now that the bug is fixed, "update `npm`" should probably be the primary advice, above the workaround. That said, I've still had to use the workaround sometimes, even with the latest `npm` (8.17.0 as of this writing).